# Can't convert and use string value in Double - Swift

Tags: swift, string, double, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have a easy problem but I can't fix it. In my program There are lines where I have a for loop with custom array. This array has got 3 value each of them string(array created by the JSON object from web). Whenever I tried the reach these string variables in double form I can't as pictures show.

[image: This is the for loop I used in app]

[image: And this is the debug report]

As you can see in the pictures my aim is get he latitude and longitude values turn into double and use in CLLocationCoordinate2D init. but the conversion of string value is for latitude = 35.32041000000002 how can I convert it into presicion 6 digit. Thanks all. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13040027/1971013) to understand floating point numbers. In summary: Not all numbers can be exactly represented in the 64-bits of a `Double`. So you'll end up with something that extremely close, but with extra digit(s), or for example with a long tail of `9999999999`.

The conversion succeeded. The value that the extra digit (`0.000000000000002`) won't hurt as they are rather insignificant.

Comment: They hurts because I can't use them in CLLocationCoordinate2D method...

Comment: Because in init method latitude and longitude values gets the double with precision 6 digit but my variables have many more

Comment: Your issue seems to be that you don't understand floating point numbers. Your program has no issue.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will read more documentation.

Comment: Good luck man. I'm sure that if you read a bit more you'll get it; it's pretty simple. We've all been there; new concepts can be very confusing in the beginning.

Comment: Have a nice day sir.